# Metalsmith and Contenful Sync

Tags: content-management-system, static-site, metalsmith

I have been using the metalsmith contenful plugin. I am wondering if maybe I have the idea of static site generators wring, but what is the purpose of this if I have to run a build every time something is changed on contentful.

Is there a way to have metalsmith on my server and have a build issued anytime contenful is changed, or is this a bad idea.

What would be recommended for keeping a site in sync with contentful more than just accessing the database with a static site generator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to automatically keep in sync a static site built using content on Contentful your best option is to use [webhooks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webhook).

Contentful provides [webhooks](https://www.contentful.com/developers/documentation/content-management-api/#resources-webhooks) which can be used for different types of events (publish, editions, etc.).